# Azure prevent administrator from accessing blobs?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to prevent the administrator from accessing user uploaded blobs? At the moment I'm using SAS uris with private containers however this doesn't stop me, the administrator, from accessing other users blob.

Thanks

Comment: Are you the storage account owner (or in other words have account key)?

Comment: If you have the account key, then essentially you have full access to the account and you (or anybody who has access to the account key) can see all data in that storage account.

Comment: I see. Is there no other way? Like.. Hash the blobs or something? Thanks

Comment: Not that I can think of. If you hash the data, how will you "unhash" (not sure if it is the right term :)) it? May be you don't want hand out the account key to a person whom you don't want to see user's data. Just a thought.

Comment: I just ran into this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rms/archive/2014/05/27/protecting-azure-blob-storage-with-azure-rms-whitepaper.aspx. See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible to achieve.  Even if you work out a mechanism for encrypting uploaded  data the administrator still has access to the storage account and containers so can extract the files (though not read the data easily).